# @Output event in Angular doesn't call its handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an event that fails to fire, it's defined as such:

```js
  private _instanceMoved: EventEmitter<InstanceMoveEvent> = new EventEmitter<InstanceMoveEvent>();


  @Output() get instanceMoved(): Observable<InstanceMoveEvent> {
    return this._instanceMoved;
  }
```

Note that using the `@Output()` directly on the property didn't change anything.

Then it's fired like this:

```js
    this._instanceMoved.next({
      instance: this.instance,
      from: originalList,
      to: targetList,
    });
```

In the receiving component it's called like this:

```html
<app-instance-move-to-list
    instance="{{instance.domain}}"
    (movingInstanceFailed)="onMovingInstanceFailed($event)"
    (instanceMoved)="onInstanceMoved($event)"
    (started)="loading = true"
/>
```

And the handler:

```js
  public async onInstanceMoved(event: InstanceMoveEvent) {
    this.instances = this.instances.filter(instance => instance.domain !== event.instance);
    this.loading = false;
  }
```

The method `onInstanceMoved()` is never called and I'm failing to see why. Note that the `(started)` event works as expected.